# s:Group arrange component on the same center

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, air

I use a s:Group to place my component in my form.
I'd like all form item have the same horizontal align inside the group.
I try to use horizontalcenter with value 0 but it doesn't work.
So I don't know how to do and I hope you can help me to solve that.

```
<s:Group width="100%" resizeMode="noScale" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0">


                        <s:FormItem label="Naissance" tabIndex="5" x="{cbQualite.x}" id="fiNaissance">
                            <mx:DateField id="dfNaissance" width="100" editable="true" 
                                          formatString="DD/MM/YYYY" yearNavigationEnabled="true"
                                          />
                        </s:FormItem>
                        <s:RadioButton id="rbFem" label="Féminin" group="{rbsex}" tabIndex="7" 
                                       x="{fiNaissance.x + fiNaissance.width+5}" 
                                       />

                        <s:RadioButton id="rbMas" label="Masculin" group="{rbsex}" tabIndex="6" x="{rbFem.width + rbFem.x + 5}" y="{fiNaissance.y +(fiNaissance.height)/2}"/>
                        <s:DropDownList id="cbDossier2" dataProvider="{DP_PAT_DOS1}" width="118" height="22" tabIndex="8" x="{cbDossier1.x}"/>
                        <s:FormItem label="" tabIndex="9" x="{fiDossier1.x}" >
                            <s:TextInput id="fDossier2" width="90" paddingRight="5" text="@{objectPatient.paDossier2}" />
                        </s:FormItem>

                    </s:Group>
```

Comment: your content does not have a clear vision, please edit if u have the screen shot add in it. then it might be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all parts of the forms inside FormItems, and put all the FormItems inside a Form.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by same horizontal align ?

If you want elements inside **Group** to be centered horizontally you must put **horizontalCenter="0"** not on the parent but on each child.

Furthermore it is a mistake to specify **width="100%"** and **horizontalCenter="0"** both on **Group**.
**width="100%"** indicates your **Group** will take all horizontal space in the parent container if the parent container layout support it. Your **Group** will automatically be centered.

Comment: I'd like that all my component have their horizontal center on the same y position. Thanks